# Magento2 How to reduce Reduce server response times (TTFB) & Eliminate render-blocking resources

Tags: magento2

How to reduce Reduce server response times (TTFB) & Eliminate render-blocking resources?

Can anyone guide me on these points?

[image]

Comment: please tell me how you did fix this issue?

Comment: Still pending @CodeForGood

Comment: Would you be kind enough to let me know once you succeed in addressing this issue? It would help many like me.

Comment: Yes I will update once I succeed